# 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: npm

I'm getting:

```
'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

when I issue:

```
npm install -g bower polyserve
```

Even though I have downloaded [node](https://nodejs.org/en/).

Answer (score 16):

I think you have not defined the path of nodejs in **Environment Variables** on the System Properties.

**Add**  `;C:\Program Files\nodejs\`   (path of your nodejs installed directory)

To the end of your Path variable on the **"User variable"** section of the **Environment Variables** on the System Properties.

Then reopen cmd prompt and type **npm** again.It should work now.Hope it helps.

You can do one more thing if still it does not work.Reboot your machine after installing node.

Comment: What is C:\Users\Owner1\AppData\Roaming\npm? That got installed too.

Comment: This is the storage location of any npm package which is installed by -g command. See you are issuing 'npm install -g bower polyserve' command.Here -g means the  global path on system and that global path is 
C:\Users\Owner1\AppData\Roaming\npm. If you issue npm command inside your project folder then all packages will be installed in that project directory itself. Check this link https://mysoftwarenotes.wordpress.com/2012/02/07/installing-npm-node-package-manager-on-windows/

Answer (score 9):

Set path for node.js in your environment variables.
To do this:

1. right click on MyComputer->properties->advance system setting-> Environment variables-> select & edit "Path" variable in System variables.
2. Add `C:\Program Files\nodejs\;` in path
3. Restart your command prompt
4. Type `node --version` in a new console window, the version number should appear as a response.

Comment: I installed & uninstalled the nodejs once and once again, and finally, after reading your answer, I found the problem was I didn't restarted the command prompt....

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows instead of directly installing a version of node, as it is common to switch between node versions for different projects. Following are the instructions to set it up.

Open PowerShell with 'Run as Administrator' option (Admin role is required for creating symlink)

Check if nvm is installed:

```
nvm version
```

If not, follow instructions on https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows#node-version-manager-nvm-for-windows to install it.

If nvm was installed, check if nodejs is in system path:

```
$Env:Path
```

If nodejs (likely 'C:\Program Files\nodejs') is not in the path and 'nodejs' symlink file exists in the directory 'C:\Program Files', then add it to the path as described by Vikas Sharma.

If 'C:\Program Files\nodejs' is in the path and symlink file doesn't exists in the directory, list installed node versions using:

```
nvm ls
```

Then create the symlink using (needs Admin role):

```
nvm use <node version>
```

Check if npm is working now:

```
npm --version
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Environment variables were all in place (as suggested by the user above). I was using node 8.9.4. Changing node version to 8.16.0 worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set system environment if you are working on windows system as above way. I would like to suggest to use `nvm` for Node environment. Recently I used nvm, and it can be switched dynamic version of node and npm by bash.

The NVM source [is here](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases).

After install, can install dynamic version of node on command line:

```
nvm install node_version
nvm use node_version
```

Answer (score 0):

If node is there but npm only not found (which is my case), then
if you have the downloaded node.js in your (windows) pc run the repair option it will do the rest.
Close the cmd window and reopen and test it by running the command

```
npm -v
```

Now it will show you the npm version.