# 'npm' is not recognized

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am creating a new project and I use npm to create a package for it, but unfortunately this time it didn't work, and when I run `npm init` it says the following in the image below:

[hyper command running npm init with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BE363.png)

```
C:\Users\HWIN10\doc\programming\intro-to-node\weatherProject>npm init
'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,  
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: probably `npm` doesn't set on your PATH? check here maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864040/fixing-npm-path-in-windows-8-and-10

Comment: Have you downloaded Node?

Comment: Check here you will see similar problem. It should be with ur file path  [File Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33055515/npm-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have node js installed in your machine you should install it first then try to use Nodejs.

Npm is automatic install after/with while installling node js.
[Nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try what this man said to do on his website.

**Open**

> Control Panel -> System and Security ->
> System -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables

In "User variables" or "System variables" find variable PATH and add node.js folder path as value.

Usually, it is `C:\Program Files\nodejs`.

If the variable doesn't exist, create it.
Restart your IDE or computer.

Try this article [node is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://love2dev.com/blog/node-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/)